# Checking battery level when ACPI has problems

Tags: acpi, battery

I am running Debian Buster (testing) / Sid on an Iball Excelance laptop (an Indian company). I initially had problems with the laptop trying to suspend and then freezing immediately after finishing booting up.  These problems went away when I included the `acpi=strict` parameter in boot-time kernel options.

However, the problem now is that there seems to be no way to get information about the battery level.  The usual `/sys/class/power_supply` is empty and `/proc/acpi` only has a `button` directory in it and a file called `wakeup`.

Is there any way around this?  Can I try some other acpi parameter at boot up (`acpi=off` won't help and in any case blocks the `i915` graphics driver, `acpi=noirq` did not stop the freezing problem)?   Or is there some other way to find out the battery level?

Comment: `man upower`, `man acpi`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `upower` command

`upower -i $(upower -e | grep 'BAT') | grep -E "state|to\ full|percentage"`